# How to access the "attribute" value inside EF object context CurrentObjectContext_SavingChanges method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wanted to use custom developed 'Auditable' attribute to track my 'POCO' objects. The objects with audit-able attribute has to be tracked for their CRUD operations. In order to do that I override the saving changes method of the object context. But I am not sure how to access the attribute value (whether the attribute is present) of each entity object, inside the saving method. Any help is appreciated...

I am using EF 6.0.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Nido.Common.Utilities.Attributes;

namespace DemoTest.Bll.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Created by MAS IT
    /// </summary>
    [Auditable]
    public class Address : BaseObject
    {
       // Your code here
    }
}
```

ObjectContext Saving method is this..

```
private void CurrentObjectContext_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // if auditable then
 // Tracking code comes here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if your attribute class is actually `AuditableAttribute` or just `Auditable`

You need to use System.Linq then you can do either:

```
if (sender !=null && 
    sender.GetType().GetCustomAttributes().OfType<AuditableAttribute>().Any())
```

or

```
if (sender !=null && 
    sender.GetType().GetCustomAttributes().OfType<Auditable>().Any())
```